# How to run use `lmer` in R to assess effect of condition, task order, and type of rating?

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme

I would like to estimate a multivariate model with the following properties:

- Fixed effects:

  1. Intercept
  2. Main effect of condition
  3. Main effect of Task order
  4. Task order X Condition interaction
- Random effects:

  1. Main effect of TypeOfRating
  2. TypeOfRating X Condition interaction
  3. TypeOfRating X Task order interaction
  4. TypeOfRating X Task order X Condition interaction

Can this be done using `lmer`?

Comment: you have asked several similar questions, this one I think is perfectly answered [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet/13173#13173). Please ask either to merge the questions or delete them.

Comment: DBR, explain what makes you think you have higher level groups in this posts.  You keep saying you want to test and effect and also it's grouping in various posts.  That's weird convoluted quantum space you're working in.  Describe what each variable is, what it means, the experiment.  Spend a paragraph or two on that because I think you're getting really stuck using terms wrong.  Stata is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: And remeber: the literature on fixed effecs and random effects isn't always consistent regarding names. So, what do you understand by fixed effects and random effects?