# Formula symbols for mixed model using lme4

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I often confuse symbols `:`, `|`, `/` and `*` in the `R` formulas, particularly when fitting mixed models with `lme4`. Can somebody explain clearly the differences between them?

*Later edit by @amoeba (Jan 2018): this question had a long and extremely confusing R code. I cut it all out for the benefit of future readers. Please see edit history if interested.*

Comment: Just to link to a related thread where [Mike Lawrence](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet/13173#13173) provided a pretty nice overview of R's formula for mixed-effects models.