# r lmer syntax for mixed model ANOVA

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have a question concerning a mixed model ANOVA conducted using the lmer function of the lme4 package. Despite a lengthy research across tutorials and forum entries I do not have a clear response to how exactly my lmer formula should be written.

#### Experimental design

32 participants take place in the study, half of which constitute the test group, the other half the control group.
Both groups do a pre and a posttest, and in both testing sessions they see 18 items of 3 conditions (= 54 items per testing session), and the stimuli of each condition are not repeated in the pre and the posttest.

My question is now if the following formula is correct/complete and if the fact that we deal here with repeated measures is automatically calculated: (dv: dependent variable)

#### Formula

```
fit1 <- lmer(dv ~ (condition * session * group) + (1|item_ID) + (1|subj_ID) + group, 
             myData, REML=FALSE)
```

Or is one of the following more accurate:

```
fit2 <- lmer(dv ~ (condition * session * group) + (1|item_ID) + (1+session|subj_ID) + group, 
             myData, REML=FALSE)

fit3 <- lmer(dv ~ (condition * session * group) + (1|item_ID) + 
             (1+session+condition|subj_ID) + group, myData, REML=FALSE)
```

I have also conducted the ANOVA comparing the three models (`anova(fit1,fit2,fit3)`) but given that these three models are not equally complex this comparison is actually not valid, is this assumption right?

Moreover, I have included the `pbkrtest` package to obtain degrees of freedom and p values; are the obtained dfs usable for reporting the inferential statistics or do I need to apply an additional transformation?

Comment: Well if I'm not mistaken it's less a question of proper implementation and more a question of which effects do you want to estimate. Models 2 and 3 include random slopes for `subj_ID` in addition to a random intercept. Do you want there to be a random slope corresponding to the effect of session for each subject (models 2 & 3) and a random slope corresponding to the effect of condition for each subject (model 3)? Should the effect of session and condition be different for different subjects? That's a theoretical question as far as I see it, not a question of implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R's lmer cheat-sheet](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet) or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70556/have-i-correctly-specified-my-model-in-lmer or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18428/formula-symbols-for-mixed-model-using-lme4