# Mixed effect modelling with multiple, nested random variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, random-variable, lme4-nlme

Goal: comparing pitch (Hz) on three types of words

Dependent variable: Hz

Fixed predictor variable: word-type, points (measurements taken from five points on each token, to capture Hz change within a token), gender (females have higher Hz)

Random variable: repetitions, which are nested within items, which are nested within speakers. Each of 15 speaker produces 5 repetitions of 5 items of the same word-type.

My question is, how do I capture the nested nature of my three random variables, with mixed effect model using R? Naively I've tried 
    `(repetition|item|speaker)`,
which obviously doesn't seem to work.

My full model, run with lme4 package, should like this:

```
lmer(hz ~ word_type + point + gender + (????), data=dataX)
```

The problem is that I am not sure I how should write my random variables (repetitions, items, and speakers).

Comment: What is your question? You ask if this kind of model is possible or about using a specific software to compute it..?

Comment: Hi Tim, I have updated my question. Hope it is clearer. I am sorry for my confusing original post..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close:

`word_type + point + gender + (1|speaker/item/repetition)`

This translates to: `repetition` nested in `item`, nested in `speaker`.

For learning more on lme4 formulas check the [in press paper by Bates et al.](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf) (published here as a vignette for lme4), [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70556/have-i-correctly-specified-my-model-in-lmer) or [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/13173/35989).

Comment: Many thanks. A follow-up question, does the order in which I list the random variables matter? (1|/item/speaker/repetition) different from (1|speaker/item/repetition)?

Comment: See my edit and the links provided.