# Crossed fixed effects model specification including nesting and repeated measures using glmm in R

Tags: r, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme, glmm, nested-data

[image]

**Background:**

I am interested in looking at the effects that `Culture`, `Treatment` and `Time` have on my response variable `Y` as well as the interactions between them whilst accounting for the nested variation between tanks and the variation caused by measuring the same individuals through time.

•    `Culture` and `Treatment` are crossed based on a figure found here: 
http://www.nature.com/nmeth/journal/v11/n10/full/nmeth.3137.html

•   As “Tanks” are exclusive to each `Treatment`, `Tank` is nested within 
`Treatment`.

•   The same 50 individuals per tank are measured through time, so `Subjects` are repeated measures.

•   As both `Culture` and `Treatment` have less than 5 levels each, I have treated them as fixed effects and I would like to extract fixed effects coefficients.

•   The Gamma distribution with `link="log"` was used because my response variable `Y` are non-integers (i.e. 0.3, 0.4 etc.).

•   I have checked the random effects observation numbers as mentioned by Dr. Ben Bolker here: ([Have I correctly specified my model in lmer?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70556/have-i-correctly-specified-my-model-in-lmer)), and the models above are able to capture the nested random nature (N=18).

•   I have chosen the `lme4` package because it is able to handle crossed designs.

•   I think that either `(1|Treatment:Tank)` or `(1|Tank)` are equivalent since the nesting of `Tank` within `Treatment` can be “discovered” from the way the data is structured, but I would like to keep it as `(1|Treatment:Tank)` to remind myself. Inferred from Dr. Doug Bates here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2009q3/002790.html

**Potential models:**

```
gamma_3 <- glmer(Y~Treatment*Culture*Time+(1|Treatment:Tank)+(1|Subject),
                 data=raw_data, family=Gamma(link="log")) 

gamma_4 <- glmer(Y~Treatment*Culture*Time+(1|Treatment:Tank)+(1|Treatment)+
                 (1|Culture)+(1|Subject), data=raw_data, family=Gamma(link="log"))
```

**Questions:**

1. Have I correctly captured the crossed nature of `Culture` and `Treatment` in model `gamma_3`? I understand that if they were treated as Random Effects it would be correct to specify them as `(1|Culture) + (1|Treatment)` as suggested by Dr. Doug Bates and Dr. Ben Bolker, respectively:  https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2009q3/002790.html and http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq

   However, I have found less resources on how to specify crossed fixed effects.
2. In model `gamma_4` I have added the above structure mentioned in question 1 [`(1|Culture) + (1|Treatment)`] in addition to keeping `Culture` and `Treatment` as Fixed effects to capture their crossed nature. However, this seems to be advised against by Dr. Ben Bolker here: [Have I correctly specified my model in lmer?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70556/have-i-correctly-specified-my-model-in-lmer)
3. Is `(1|Subject)` sufficient to specify repeated measures in the `glmm()` context?
4. Finally, I am getting the following error message although the model does produced an output:

   a) `fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 5 columns / coefficients`

   This was surprising to me because I have heaps of data. I have 50 individuals per tank, 3 tanks per treatment etc.

   b) `Warning message:In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.101624 (tol = 0.001, component 1)`

   Why would the model fail to converge but still produced an output? Any clues on how I can fix this or glean some more information on the nature of the error?

---

Note: Also, a tag for crossed designs does not seem to exist. Potentially someone with a high enough reputation could create a new tag if they find it useful or correct for this community?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Yes.  `*` in (R's version of) Wilkinson-Rogers notation specifies "interaction plus all lower level terms", so (ignoring `Time` for the moment) `Treatment*Culture` is equivalent to `1 + Treatment + Culture + Treatment:Culture`.  If you wanted `Treatment` *nested* within `Culture` you would use `Culture/Treatment` = `1 + Culture + Culture:Treatment` (i.e. omit main effect of `Treatment`.  Note, however, that for fixed effects specifying nesting vs crossing changes the model parameterization, but the overall fit (e.g. number of parameters, predictions of the model, log-likelihood, etc.) is the same for nesting vs. crossing.
2. This is a bad idea, not just because it's almost impossible to fit a random effect when the grouping variable has only 2 levels, but because your model is now overfitted - you've included `Culture` as *both* a random effect and a fixed effect.
3. Depends what you mean by "repeated measures".  It does specify that samples within an individual are not independent.  However, you might want to consider variation in *slopes* among individuals `(Time|Subject)` (if `Time` is being considered as a continuous covariate), or consider temporal autocorrelation (not possible in `lme4`, but in `nlme` using e.g. `correlation=corAR1()`
4. (a) You're probably treating `Time` as a factor (categorical predictor) and have some times missing for some culture/treatment combinations?  (That's technically a "message", not an "error message".) `attr(getME(fitted_model,"X"),"col.dropped")` should tell you the column numbers and names of the variables that were dropped. (b) have you looked at `?convergence` ?

You could actually use `nlme::lme` for this problem if you wanted, by (1) using log-Normal instead of Gamma responses, (2) fitting `Subject` nested within `Tank` ...

```
lme(Y~Treatment*Culture+Time,random=~1|Tank/Subject),data=raw_data)
```