# GLMM multilevel (hierarchical) model

Tags: glmm

I want to study the classroom and the school effect/result on the pupil's success (or not) at school.
I also want to know the effect of the age, the gender (of the pupils) and if the pupils have or not repeated 1 year school on the pupil's success (or not).

The pupil's variables are : 
- the age, (11 or 12)
- the gender, (male or female)
- if they have repeated one year, (yes or not)
- the success, (yes or not)

The other variables are : 
- the classroom they belong to, (A or B)
- the school they belong to, (C or D)

I would like to proceed by GLMM, more precisely a multilevel (hierarchical) model using R on my dataset knowing that firstly I am looking for the effect of the classroom and the effect of the school on the pupil's success (or not) and secondly I want to know the effect of the age, the gender and if the pupils have (or not) repeated one year ? 
Many thanks for your help !

Comment: Sounds like you know exactly what you want to do. What's stopping you for building the model?

Comment: In addition to what charles said, there are some excellent threads in this forum on how to use `lme4`. (eg. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31569/questions-about-how-random-effects-are-specified-in-lmer and/or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40670/understanding-the-random-effect-in-linear-mixed-models-lme4-r )

Comment: Hi Charles and user11852, Thanks for your comments. Yes I guess I know what I want to do, but I don't know how to do it using R. That is my problem. Thanks for your help !

Comment: In a less technical and more general note: if you only have two classes and two schools, there's not much point to building a mixed model, you should probably just use a regular generalized linear model with school and classroom within school as fixed effects.  See http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already pointed out by Ben Bolker, I think a GLMM might not be the adequate analysis strategy for you, although it might seem appropriate at first due to the nested structure of classes in schools. However, as the `lme4` [faq tells](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq#toc32) you:

> One point of particular relevance to 'modern' mixed model estimation
>   (rather than 'classical' method-of-moments estimation) is that, for
>   practical purposes, there must be a reasonable number of
>   random-effects levels (e.g. blocks) — more than 5 or 6 at a minimum.

As you have only two levels, for your random factor school and only two or four levels for class, running a `glmm` will not work properly.

Simply run a binomial `glm` on your dv, e.g.:

```
m1 <- glm(success ~ age + gender + repeated + school * class, family = binomial, 
      data = your.df)
summary(m1)
```

Comment: Hi, Many thanks Ben Bolker and Henrik for your response. I will apply a binomial glm. Best

Comment: Hi, one last thing, supposing that I had more than 6 random effect levels, I should use a GLMM model. How could I do my GLMM model using R ? Thanks !

Comment: @varinsacha This is not a trivial question and cannot be answered in the comments. Please ask a new question for this and make sure to include a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/289572). This is probably necessary.

Comment: Hi Henrik, thanks once more for your response. I have just posted my GLMM problem with R Thanks for your help !