# simple repeated measures syntax - lme vs. lmer

Tags: r, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

I'm trying to look for significant effects on "similarity" (of "isinpair" and controlling for time effects) using repeated measures with an in group sample. The intervention "isinpair" occurs after a short period of time (time intervals aren't equivalent, but there are many occuring with in a relative short time).

The question seems a variation of [R's lmer cheat-sheet](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet/13173#13173)

Unfortunately, I am quite hazy about the syntax (and underlying statistical differences) of `lme` vs. `lmer`. I've seen both recommended for similar tasks.

1. Are these two examples accomplishing what I intend? How equivalent / different are they? Which is better illustrating what I'm hoping to examine?

   ```
   lmer(similarity ~ 1 +time*isinpair +(time*isinpair|user1), data=nozeros) 

   lme(similarity ~ isinpair*time, random=list(user1=pdBlocked(list(~1, 
                      pdIdent(~isinpair-1), pdIdent(~time-1)))), data=nozeros)
   ```
2. How does this compare to:

   ```
   aov(simscore ~ isinpair * time + Error(user1), data = nozerosdemo))
   ```