# What does (1|g1/g2) mean in a lmer formula?

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme

What does this formula mean?

```
lmer(y ~ (1|g1/g2))
```

equivalently:

```
lmer(y ~ (1|g1) + (1|g1:g2)
```

According to the PDF that I found it in, linked [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf), it means:

"Intercept varying among g1 and g2 within g1"

I would love it if someone would elaborate on this, and would differentiate it from, say

```
lmer(y ~ (0 + g2|g1))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the answer available at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet/13173#13173?

Comment: @whuber, I'm a big fan of that answer, but I wonder if there is some room for someone to elaborate specifically on the nesting syntax `/` & how that relates to the more common syntax.

Comment: @whuber I really did see that post before (have the tab open from the morning). Mike Lawrence does an awesome job in that answer and it cleared up a lot of things for me. However, no where in that answer is there syntax like (1|g1/g2) or (1|g1:g2) and I believe, based on the syntax in the pdf linked in the question, that this means something different.