# Translating lmer syntax with fixed effects, covariate and random intercepts in a "conventional" or standardised way

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, notation

I have the following `lmer()` syntax:

```
 lmer(Y ~ A*B*C + COV + A:COV + B:COV + C:COV + (1|A:BLOCK))
```

where `A`, `B` and `C` are the fixed effects and `COV` is a continuous covariate. In a manuscript I am writing, I explained that I am using a linear mixed effects model with `A`, `B` and `C` as the fixed effects, `COV` as the covariate, also used in interactions with `A`, `B` and `C`. I also modelled a random intercept for every observed combination of `A` and `BLOCK` to account for variation in blocks. I also list the outputs and `lmer` model description in the appendix. The reviewer however, want the model to be described in a "conventional way" in the text. I am not 100% sure what the reviewer means by  "conventional" but I am assuming he/she refers to the mathematical representation of the `lmer` syntax above?

Alternatively, I was thinking something along this way (but I am not sure how to add the covariate and the random term, see the "$\dots$"):

$$Y_{ijk}=\mu+A_i+B_j+C_k+(AB)_{ij}+(AC)_{ik}+(BC)_{jk}+ ... +\epsilon_{ijk}$$

I appreciate any help regarding the translation of this `lmer` syntax.

Comment: See [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61466/26743).

Comment: Thanks @Livius ! Do you know how to express a nested random term?

Comment: Nesting is handled automagically by `lme4`. The only caveat is that your nested identifiers need to be unique (so if you have 1 through 5 nested in a, b, c, then you either need to rename 1 to 5 as a1 ... a5, b1, ..., b5 etc. OR use the interaction/nesting syntax). The important thing is each level of whatever grouping you assume (whether nested, crossed, whatever) is uniquely named. See 2.2.1.1 in [this](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/lMMwR/lrgprt.pdf) or the Pastes example in [this](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/slides/2011-03-16-Amsterdam/1Simple.pdf).