# Lmer notation for the random intercept model (x~1|label)

Tags: regression, mixed-model, notation, lme4-nlme

According to e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61466/14346, the following simple model:
$$
x_{label} = a_{label} + e_{label} 
$$
writes in lmer syntax as:

```
x~1|label
```

However, I do not manage to understand this formulation : What is the meaning of this when dealing with multiple observations i.e. multiple (and different) observations $x_{label}$ for a given label ?

Comment: Could you please provide a more specific title?

Comment: I did it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I could not find that model in the link, but that is probably not that important. I assume that in $a_{label}+e_{label}$ $a$ stands for a constant and $e$ for an error term. Thus $x_{label} = a_{label} + e_{label}$ means, that there is a constant for every $label$ that is measured with some error. 
Translation to lmer is `x~1|label` where 1 stands for the intercept or constant and `|label`stands for "different for each label" and `~`that there is an error term.

Comment: (+1) Maybe it would help to write a generative model for this case: $$x\sim \mathcal N(a + a_i, \sigma^2),\;\;\; a_i \sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma_a^2),$$ where $i$ indexes labels/groups. The `lmer` function will fit these three parameters to the data.

Comment: So is the equivalent model: $x_{j,l} = a_l + e_{j,l}$ with $e_{j,l} \sim N(0,\sigma^2_l)$ ? which is for me not the same that those given in the examples.

Comment: @pheup Not quite. See my comment above.

Comment: @peuhp Yes. Sticking with the $x_{level}=a_{level}+e_{level}$ notation one would expect the error $e$ to be normally distributed around 0. Moreover, the random effect $a_{level}$ is also considered to be randomly distributed around some $a$, which is denoted in amoebas comment but not in my answer.

Comment: @Bernhard. My point is about $x_{j,l}=a_l+e_{j,l}$ with $e_{jl} \sim N(0,\sigma^2_l)$ is not the same than $x_{j,l}=a_l+e_{l}$ with $e_{l} \sim N(0,\sigma^2_l)$ and that the notation is not clear on that.

Answer (score 2):

The full formula is

```
x ~ 1 + 1|label
```

what translates to model with a global intercept and random intercepts for each group `label`.

[image: Hierarchical model diagram]

In probabilistic notation this translates to the following model

$$
\begin{align}
x_i &\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu + \alpha_j, \sigma^2_0) \\
\alpha_j &\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2_\alpha)
\end{align}
$$

where $\mu$ is a global intercept, $\alpha_j$ are random intercepts specific for observations in each $j$-th group and there is normal "noise" on both levels.