# "Random effects must be less than the number of observations" error in lmer package with categorical predictors

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I know similar error messages were discussed before, but my question is different than those.

I have a model in the following form:
$$Y_{ij} = \alpha_jX_i+ \beta_j + \epsilon_{ij} $$

Here $\beta_j$ is a categorical variable (Group), $\alpha_j$ is a random slope for each group, $X_i$ is a categorical variable to identify each subject, and $Y_{ij}$ is subject $i$'s contribution to group $j$.

When I write this model in *lmer*, I use the following model function:

```
contrib ~ Subj + Grp + (Subj+0|Grp)
```

I don't have observations for all `Subj-Grp` combinations. Some subjects only participate in some groups. When running this model, if my `Subj` is a continuous variable, then I don't get any error message.
But if my `Subj` is a categorical variable to identify each subject, I get the following error message:

```
Error: number of observations  <= number of random effects for term 
(0 + Subj | Grp); the random-effects parameters and the residual 
variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable
```

Is there a way to use a `lmer` model for such cases with imbalanced data? 
Any conceptual explanation about the differences of a model with a random slope for a categorical variable vs. continuous variable would be really helpful.

**Edit:** as requested, this is the scenario I am trying to model. Subjects in the study are members of multiple groups. But not every subject is part of every group. So I think this is not a fully nested design (?). I  measure the quality of the contribution of each subject to each group they contribute to ($Y_{ij}$ is such a measure). This measurement could be due to the properties of the subject and the group. That is why I am including categorical variables for the subject and the group. However the subject could have different quality of contribution in different groups. Hence I include a random slope $\alpha_j$. When I got the error message for subject as a categorical variable, I tried to replace it with a continuous value for the subject (average quality measurement across all groups the subject participate in). What I am interested in finding from the model is $\alpha_j$ (i.e., how much a subject vary in different groups).

Answer (score 1):

Just as a note, it would be really helpful if you provided some more specific examples of the data you are fitting to the model. I'm assuming it's longitudinal. That said here are some thoughts:

I think you are mispecifying the model. The reason you can run the model when you treat individuals continuously is that `lmer` is estimating the slopes of the variable `subj`. If you think about the `lmer` formula, you are estimating a random effect (i.e. slope) across subjects, which is probably not meaningful. There is a great primer to `lmer` formulas: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet). You probably can't estimate a random effect across a factor in this case (I'm actually not sure how that works out more generally - I'm not 100% sure it's statistically erroneous, so I'll leave that to someone that knows for sure). You should probably be estimating random intercepts for individuals - which can be nested in group, if you feel like that's what you're trying to do: 
`lmer(contrib~Group+(1|Subj/Group), data=data)` Or something like that.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. I added some explanation about the data. My data is not a fully nested structure. When I tried your suggestion with `lmer(contrib~Group+(1|Subj/Group), data=data)`, it gives another error message `Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations`. Any clarification would be useful!

Comment: Specifically what question are you trying to answer? Is your data longitudinal?

Comment: No it is not longitudinal. I want to rank Subjects based on $\alpha_j$. Does it clarify your question? @Mik