# Testing for between-samples factor with linear mixed models

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, anova, biostatistics

I have data from an experiment including 5 biological replicates, each of which has 3 technical replicates. These 5 samples are divided into 2 groups (condition *a* and contidion *b*). **My goal is to test wether *dv* of samples in condition *a* is different to *dv* of samples in condition *b* or not.** 

Here follows the design matrix (`dt`).

```
   sample replicate condition        dv
1       1         1         a 1.3736170
2       1         2         a 0.8432886
3       1         3         a 1.4026123
4       2         1         a 0.5778786
5       2         2         a 0.9767180
6       2         3         a 0.5853707
7       3         1         b 0.9844947
8       3         2         b 1.0369401
9       3         3         b 1.0300460
10      4         1         b 1.4529099
11      4         2         b 1.0600300
12      4         3         b 0.9304093
13      5         1         b 1.3188977
14      5         2         b 1.2196227
15      5         3         b 1.0311674
```

What I would normally do is to take the average *dv* of technical replicates in each sample (`dt.mean`) and then perform an ANOVA test between samples in condition a and samples in condition b as follows.

```
  sample condition   mean_dv
1      1         a 1.2065060
2      2         a 0.7133224
3      3         b 1.0171603
4      4         b 1.1477831
5      5         b 1.1898959

anova(lm(mean_dv~condition, data=dt.mean))
```

I was wondering wether mixed models could allow me to test similar hypothesis without aggregation of technical replicates. As far as I understood, my approach would be to fit two linear mixed models (with or without `condition` as fixed effect) and then compare them with ANOVA:

```
mod0 <- lmer(data = dt, dv ~ (1|sample))
mod1 <- lmer(data = dt, dv ~ condition + (1|sample))
anova(mod0, mod1)
```

**Is this a correct work-flow and does it apply to this problem?**
**Does it work when testing for *between samples* factors with replicates?**

I already found similar questions, but with slightly different experimental desings in which each sample was tested in both conditions (a and b) like [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352871/biological-and-technical-replicates-mixed-model).

**EDIT**
For anyone interest in the answer, I finally found a nice reference [book](https://psyteachr.github.io/stat-models-v1/linear-mixed-effects-models-with-one-random-factor.html). Under the chapter 6.2 it shows a similar example to the one I reported. It explains how it is possible to test for a between-subjects factor in presence of pseudo-replication (which is my case).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which part in the linked [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/352884/176202) remains unanswered for your question?

Comment: Hi Frans! In the linked question each biological sample was measured under both conditions ("control" and "treatment"). As far as I understood, this can be treated as a **repeated measures** problem. In my case, I don't have repeated measures (biological samples are divided into two groups), and I was wondering wether proposed workflow still applies. Moreover, I am interested in understanding the detailed advantages over technical replicates aggregation.