# lme4 syntax for random effect nested under fixed and random effects

Tags: anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have data looking at the performance of thousands of one-vs-all binary classifiers trained for an image recognition task under different conditions.

I'm trying to use `lme4` to predict classifier performance (`dprime`), given: (`featureSet`) a fixed effect of which of 5 feature sets was used to train the classifier; (`nTrainingExamples`) a continuous fixed effect of the number of examples used to train the classifier; and (`category`) a random effect of the category the classifier was trained to recognize.

So far so good. Based on the [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#model-specification) and the [lme4 cheatsheet](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet) and this [Conjugate Prior post](http://conjugateprior.org/2013/01/formulae-in-r-anova/) (among many others), I have:

```
 dprime ~ featureSet * nTrainingExamples + (1 | category)
```

The wrinkle is that I have another factor (`split`): I sampled 20 unique training sets for each combination of `featureSet`, `nTrainingExamples` and `category`. I could have sampled many more training sets for each combination, so I think this is a random effect. I have no idea, however, how to describe this sort of nesting.

**How do I specify a random effect nested under both fixed and random effects?**

I had tried:

```
dprime ~ featureSet * nTrainingExamples + (1 | category/split)
```

but that only nests `split` under `category`, right, and not under the fixed factors?

**Whatever the correct model is, is it something that I could appropriately model using a classical ANOVA mixed-effects-models? If so, what's the syntax for specifying this model for `aov`?**