# Compare using `lme4` and `nlme` for mixed effects models

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

Sorry it might be a more Stack Overflow question but I was reading this nice cheat sheet for using function `lmer` in package `lme4` in `R`, and 
[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet/13173#13173) is the link on Cross Validated. I will give a screenshot as below:

[image]

So I was wondering could anyone help create a similar cheat sheet for using function `lme` in package `nlme`?

I was reading the general examples for using `lme` as
[image]

The examples are very limited. It seems if we do not specify the `random` part in `lme`, then the variables list in the fixed effect part will also be considered as random.

Answer (score 1):

Function `lme()` also works with a special class of data frames defined in package **nlme**, which are called `groupedData`. In this data frame a formula for the grouping structure is provided that `lme()` directly uses if the `random` argument is not specified. If you don't use a `groupedData` (that contains the random-effects structure) and do not specify the `random` argument, `lme()` will through an error.

Comment: But how does this answer the question `So I was wondering could anyone help create a similar cheat sheet for using function lme in package nlme`?