# Contrast between linear mixed-effects model and two-way ANOVA

Tags: regression, mixed-model, anova, linear-model

Let $Y$ a real positive variable. I have a data frame with the measurements $X = mean(Y)$ of four distinct categories of subjects:

- Healthy control during control condition
- Healthy control during experimental condition
- Diagnosed during control condition
- Diagnosed control during experimental condition

The data frame then looks as follows:

```
Subject | SessionType | Subject Group | mean(Y)
   1          Control        Healthy       x1
   1          Exp            Healthy       x2
   2          Control        Depressed     x3
   2          Exp            Depressed     x4
```

and so on.

I want to compare the means of `mean(Y)` across `SessionType` and `SubjectGroup` using ANOVA (assume the conditions for this test are met). Since each subject is contributing two values, one for each sesion type, I must use a repeated measures ANOVA. But I was also suggested to fit a mixed linear-effects model on the data.

What would a mixed linear-effects model reveal in this context, and in contrast with what the ANOVA test would reveal?

Comment: There are quite many questions and answers here about this exact issue: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24314/when-is-a-repeated-measures-anova-preferred-over-a-mixed-effects-model and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/397540/why-use-linear-mixed-models-instead-of-repeated-measures-anova for instance