# Why would the following two specifications of linear mixed model give different SE and variance components estimates?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Take the "Orthodont" dataset from "nlme" for an example. Let's say we want to fit a linear mixed effect model "distance ~ age + random intercept + random slope for age". It seems to me that the following two specifications are equivalent. However, they produce different SE and variance components estimates.

`library(nlme)
data("Orthodont") 
m.reml1 <- lmer(distance ~ age + (age | Subject), data = Orthodont, REML = T)
m.reml2 <- lmer(distance ~ age + (1 | Subject) + (0 + age | Subject), data = Orthodont, REML = T)
summary(m.reml1)
summary(m.reml2)`

From `m.reml1`, we get SE 0.77525 and 0.07125 for `(Intercept)` and `age`.

From `m.reml2`, we get SE 0.71380 and 0.06561 for `(Intercept)` and `age`.

The variance components are also different.

So why the difference? Are they really specifying different models?

Comment: You'll find the answer to your question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first model assumes that the random intercepts and random slopes for age are correlated, whereas the second one assumes that they are independent.