# Syntax of the bmrs package, specifically the model structure ...+(1 | V1 | V2). Complementing the R's lmer cheat sheet

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

Much discussion has been made about the syntax of different mixed models with the lmer package. This [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet?newreg=8fa0622c11304d228de62b87c0b2426a) describes a great summary on the subject. But I didn't find anything talking specifically about the following structure:

... + (1 | group 1 | group 2)

or following the language addressed by Barr et al. (2013) mentioned by [@Livius](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet?newreg=8fa0622c11304d228de62b87c0b2426a), following structure:

... + (1 | Subject | Item)

Could you explain what a model with this structure means?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: To what extent are intricacies of various R packages on topic here?

Comment: Specifically with the brm() function from the brms package. Several packages I would say. In general, the topic is about the syntax of multilevel, hierarchical, and mixed effect models, among other names. Would you be able to answer on the subject? I thank you for your attention.

Comment: Don't know enough about these to be a good guide. Suggest you browse around. Questions about specific types of statistical analyses are appropriate here. Also methods of analysis of data from related designs. Questions about specific software are probably best answered in other forums.  Maybe you can get ideas about related kinds of studies, and analyses of them, leading up to the structure in your question. Maybe others will see your question and have different advice.

Comment: Thank you very much @BruceET !!!!