# What is the difference between these two mixed model specifications?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, jasp

I've been running several mixed linear models in R. I use the `lmer` function from lmerTest. I also ran the same analyses (or so I thought) in JASP. JASP uses R behind the scenes and shows you the R code. It turns out that JASP constructs a different model (see 1 below) than I did (see 2 below).

Short question: What is the difference between the two model specifications below?

Model 1:

```
value ~ variable + (1 + variable | topic) + (1 + variable | ResponseId)
```

Model 2:

```
value ~ variable + (1|ResponseId) + (1|topic)
```

- **value** is a continuous dependent variable.
- **variable** and **topic** are within-subject random variables (factor)
- **ResponseId** is the subject id (factor)

Answer (score 0):

There is another, more general, question on StackExchange: [R's lmer cheat sheet](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13166/127570). The resources linked there might be able to address my question. In particular, it seems that the form

(1 + ResponseId)

only allows for a random intercept per responseId. In contrast, the form

(1 + variable | responseId)

fits different slopes (for the effect of the variable) and different intercepts for each responseId.

It would be nice if someone more knowledgeable could confirm (or correct).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Greetings! This should not be posted as an answer, as it doesn't provide a solution to the question.