# model formulas for glmer

Tags: r, logistic, lme4-nlme, odds

I have a glmer (library lme4) logit model that I conducted in R. I have very basic knowledge in stats and glmm models are completely new to me. My Models in R basically are like this:

```
 mylogit_inst <- glmer(success_1 ~ inst + (1|fish_ID), data = results, family = "binomial")
 mylogit_s <- glmer(success_1 ~ inst_diff_1 +(1+inst_diff_1|fish_ID), data = results, family = "binomial")
```

What would be the matematical formula of these Models above based on log ODDs? Or I also appreciate a good source explaining the math behind it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some resources that can help.

The [UCLA Introduction to Generalized Linear Mixed Models](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/introduction-to-generalized-linear-mixed-models/) nicely works up from linear mixed models in general to what's meant by a "generalized" linear mixed model.

There is a related R Data Analysis Example on [Mixed Effects Logistic Regression](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/mixed-effects-logistic-regression/) that goes into great detail on how to set up and work with the results of a mixed logistic regression.

This site's [lmer cheat sheet](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13166/28500) explains how the notation corresponds to what coefficient values the model will try to estimate.

For both your models, what's hidden is the default logit (log-odds) link for the binomial generalized linear regression regression. If $y$ is the 1/0 outcome, then both models fit the logit of the expectation of $y$, $E(y)$, with respect to a linear predictor $\eta$:

$$\text{logit}(E(y))=\eta. $$

The linear predictor is what you provide on the right side of the formula, and differs for your two models. For a mixed model, this is often written in a matrix form:

$$\eta= X\beta +Z \gamma,$$

where $X$ represents the fixed-effect predictors with corresponding coefficients $\beta$ and $Z$ represents the random effects with corresponding coefficients $\gamma$. Each of your models only has a single fixed-effect predictor (`inst` or `inst_diff_1`).

The cheat sheet shows that the first model has random intercepts in the linear predictor associated with `fish_ID`; those are modeled as having a Gaussian distribution with 0 mean and variance estimated from the data. The second model has both random intercepts and random slopes (with respect to `inst_diff_1`) associated with `fish_ID`, again modeled as Gaussian distributions with 0 means and variances estimated from the data. The cheat sheet shows that, in the form you specified, a correlation between the random intercepts and slopes is also estimated.