# The correct implementation of random effects

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I apologize because frankly no matter how many stack exchange posts I read, I read the lmer [cheat sheet](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet), online guides, and even helpful [articles](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/2515245920960351) yet random effects just do not make much sense.

My analysis uses a general mixed effect model on binary values "choice" using glmer() in the lme4 passage. The independent variables are the within-subject continuous variable "EV" (expected value) and categorical variable "magnitude" which basically separates the data into three blocks corresponding to the three magnitude conditions and directly affects the presentation of EV to the participants.

Currently here are the counts:

- **Subjects**: 40 subjects after cleaning
- **EV**: In one experiment, there are 11 variations of EV (-5 to +5) while another experiment has EV determined by a staircase function. In both cases, EV is meant to be treated as continuous.
- **Magnitude**: 3 magnitude blocks (which are categorical) that are meant to multiply EV by 1,2 or 4, but I transform the EV values back to their original values (-5 to +5) in the analysis.
- **Combinations**: I have 44 EV trials per magnitude block (so 132 trials total). Therefore for the EVs not represented as a staircase, I have 12 observations per combination of EVxMagnitude

The two hypotheses are that "magnitude" affects the binary dependent variable "choice" as well as moderates the effect EV has on the dependent variable "choice". I believe I understand the fixed effects but I am unsure if I am correctly accounting for the within-subject variance in the form of random effects. Here is a simplified (without sum coding or optimization) version of the script.

```r
model<- glmer(Choice ~ 1 + EV:Magnitude  + 
               (1 + EV|Subject) + (1 + Magnitude|Subject) + 
               (1 + EV:Magnitude|Subject),
               data = CVTclean)
```

If I am correct, `(1 + EV|Subject)` is meant to account for intercept and slope of EV on choice between subjects while `(1 + EV:Magnitude|Subject)` accounts for every permutation of the interaction between EV and magnitude on choice between subjects. When I run this model, I get a singular fit and I am told that this means my model is overfitted so I begin to remove random effects. However, it is not evident in the first place which random effects I should include a priori. If my variable of interest is the effect of magnitude, does adding in a random effect of magnitude just stifle any power to find a fixed effect of magnitude?

Confusingly still, using a likelihood ratio test for differences in random effect inclusions, seems to indicate that each inclusing of random effects improves the model

```r
Models:
CVT_Medr.mod: Choice ~ 1 + EV * Magnitude + (1 + EV | Subject)
CVT_Highr.mod: Choice ~ 1 + EV * Magnitude + (1 + EV | Subject) + 
                          (1 + Magnitude | Subject)
CVT_Full.mod: Choice ~ 1 + EV * Magnitude + (1 + EV | Subject) + 
                          (1 + Magnitude | Subject) + 
                          (1 + EV:Magnitude | Subject)
              npar    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance   Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
CVT_Medr.mod     9 5597.1 5656.2 -2789.5   5579.1                          
CVT_Highr.mod   15 5571.3 5669.9 -2770.7   5541.3  37.758  6  1.253e-06 ***
CVT_Full.mod    25 5431.6 5595.9 -2690.8   5381.6 159.696 10  < 2.2e-16 ***
```

Although note that one of the models does not converge.

Long story short.

- Can magnitude be treated like a fixed and random effect?
- Is using something like `(1 + Magnitude|Subject)` or even `(1 + EV:Magnitude|Subject)` good to account for the variance between subjects?
- Am I worrying too much about random effects and should just use a simple random effects which converge?